# Creating a Controller for NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsoutlineview

I'm having an issue with regards to creating a separate Controller class for an NSOutlineView I have.

I've created a new class named `LTSidebarViewController` and in my MainMenu.xib file I've added an Object to the 'workbench' and linked it to my `LTSidebarViewController` class.  I've also set the delegate and datasource to be linked to the NSOutlineView in MainMenu.xib.

What I am looking to do is create an instance of this class from within `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` in my AppDelegate file and when I do so I want to pass in the App Delegate's managedObjectContext.  So, I've created a custom `init` method in `LTSidebarViewController` which looks like so:

```
-(id)initWithManagedObject:(NSManagedObjectContext*)managedObject{

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.managedObjectContext = managedObject;

        NSFetchRequest *subjectsFetchReq = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
        [subjectsFetchReq setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Subject"
                                                inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];

        subjectsArray = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:subjectsFetchReq error:nil];

        _topLevelItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"SUBJECTS", nil];

        // The data is stored in a  dictionary
        _childrenDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [_childrenDictionary setObject:subjectsArray forKey:@"SUBJECTS"];

        // The basic recipe for a sidebar
        [_sidebarOutlineView sizeLastColumnToFit];
        [_sidebarOutlineView reloadData];
        [_sidebarOutlineView setFloatsGroupRows:NO];

        // Set the row size of the tableview
        [_sidebarOutlineView setRowSizeStyle:NSTableViewRowSizeStyleLarge];

        // Expand all the root items; disable the expansion animation that normally happens
        [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
        [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:0];
        [_sidebarOutlineView expandItem:nil expandChildren:YES];
        [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];

        // Automatically select first row
        [_sidebarOutlineView selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] byExtendingSelection:NO];
    }
    return self;

}
```

I also have all the required methods in this class, `- (NSView *)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn item:(id)item` etc.

Inside the `- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification` method in the App Delegate, I have the following:

```
    LTSidebarViewController *sidebarViewController = [[LTSidebarViewController alloc] initWithManagedObject:self.managedObjectContext];
```

My problem is that this isn't working, I don't get any errors and the app runs but no data is displayed in the NSOutlineView.

Now from what I can tell the problem is that when the MainMenu.xib file is initially loaded, it's automatically creating an instance of my `LTSidebarViewController` class and calling it's init method but because my init method isn't doing anything the app doesn't finish launching correctly.

Am i taking the correct approach here? In simple terms all I'm looking for is to have a separate file that is used as the datasource for my NSOutlineView.

Answer (score 1):

When working with NSOutlineView I generally put in extreme amounts of logging to figure out what's going on.  I would probably do something like the following (maybe you have already done some of this):

Make sure you really have data in subjectsArray by logging it, e.g.

```
NSLog(@"subjectsArray");
NSLog(@"%@", subjectsArray);
```

Make sure you have implemented the NSOutlineView Datasource protocol methods from [NSOutlineView Datasource Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSOutlineViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSOutlineViewDataSource) in your AppDelegate.m file and that they're returning the appropriate data.

- If you need help implementing these, try a tutorial such as [Source Lists and NSOutlineView](http://benreimers.net.au/blog/sources-lists-and-nsoutlineview).
- I usually wind up with NSLog statements in each of the NSOutlineView data source methods to make sure they are being called and that I understand what each is expecting and returning.

Make sure your delegate and datasource are not nil for some reason in your `initWithManagedObject:(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObject` method by logging them, e.g.

```
NSLog(@"datasource: %@", [self datasource]);
NSLog(@"delegate: %@", [self delegate]);
```

If you find that for some reason they are nil, you could manually set them just to make sure that's not the problem, e.g. in initWithManagedObject:

```
[self setDelegate: [NSApp delegate]];
[self setDatasource: [NSApp delegate]];
```

As far as whether this is the "correct" approach: I'm not clear from your code whether you're intending that the sideBarController is both the `delegate` and the `datasource` or whether the `AppDelegate` is serving those roles.  Obviously, you'll need to implement the `delegate` and `datasource` protocols in the appropriate files.  You certain can have `AppDelegate` serve those roles, although it seems to make more sense to have your sideBarController do that.

A small note: I sometimes access AppDelegate's managedObjectContext directly from supporting files with something like

```
-(NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
return [[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext];
}
```

rather than passing the managedObjectContext in manually to every file.

Comment: Thanks for that information, particularly the method for accessing AppDelegate's managedObjectContext, that will make life a lot easier.

Comment: I should have said that I am looking for `LTSidebarViewController` to be the delegate and the data source.  The problem appears to be that because `LTSidebarViewController` is the dataSource, it is being initialised before the AppDelegate and because the AppDelegate has the required information (managedObjectContext) it's not working.

Comment: If that's the case, perhaps the accessing the NSApp delegate's managedObjectContext would get around that as then the LTSidebarViewController should have access when its data source methods get called.

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback @user196015.  I'm still having issues so I've asked a new question that explains what's happening in greater detail [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513121/cocoa-core-data-accessing-app-delegate-and-managedobjectcontext[/link]